# C# code to Hide toolbars in an excel document

Tags: c#, excel-2003

I have a C# Winforms program that opens an excel document with the code below.
It works great but what I can not figure out how to do, is to turn off ALL menu's and toolbars.

The excel version I am using right now is 2003... But I will be upgrading to 2010 in the near future.
Any ideas?

```
//top of source...
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

// Code inside a function...

// Get report and display it on the screen.
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlApp.Visible = true;
xlApp.DisplayFullScreen = true;

 // Display the Document and then Sleep.
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeToShowMilliseconds);

// Close the Excel report 
 xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into your case and i think with [Excel.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application_members.aspx) you can find the answer.

Apparently what you need to do is something like this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
xlApp.CommandBars("tabName").Controls("File").Enabled = false;
```

try it and let me know, if it doesnt work we'll figure something out.

Comment: When I do use the xlApp.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False; code, I get an error... Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application.CommandBars' cannot be used like a method. and if I change it to... xlApp.CommandBars["Worksheet Menu Bar"].Enabled = False; Cannot apply indexing with [] to expression of type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBars'

Comment: I tested by disabling (`Enabled=false`) all the commadbars but this does not have any effect. Despite the value being correctly applied.